# What does Oracle-apex SyntaxError : unexpected token means?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

So I'm using the Apex office print (AOP) plugin for printing the reports from Oracle Apex. After I created a process which prints the document by clicking the button, there is an error: 
"Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0".
Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a hint that some JSON is malformed

You should consider the information presented by the AOP team on this particular error, and compare that with your situation.

https://www.apexofficeprint.com/docs/index.html#1012-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-p-in-json-at-position-0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using APEX 5.1 or above, the Dynamic Action plug-in will always work, whereas the Process plug-in might give this JSON error.

The AOP process in the Processing part will only work if the “Reload on Submit” attribute (of the page) is set to “Always”. Since APEX 5.1 and above that attribute is set to “Only for Success” and then the process plug-in is not working.

Alternative you can put the AOP Process to be After Header, and make it conditional than it will work regardless of the setting of "Reload on Submit".

We recommend using the AOP dynamic action.